# Azure P2S connection with VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I set up an Azure VPN as per this document 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-classic-azure-portal

Also I have created an Azure Windows VM.

My question is how can I connect my Azure VM through this Azure Point to Site VPN connection .  I have added a password in security page while I export client certificate in VPN setup , but Azure VPN is not asking for the password before it gets connected . My Azure VM is just connecting via normal rdp. How can I add extra security with vpn by using a password before i login to my Azure VM.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have added a password in security page while I export client
>   certificate in VPN setup

The password used for certificate, when you want to install this certificate, we need this password.

> How can I add extra security with vpn by using a password before i
>   login to my Azure VM.

Because you had install certificate in your PC, so when you connect your VPN, Azure will not ask for password.

The certificate replaces the password. For now, Azure P2S VPN does **not** support use password authentication.

Comment: As a workaround, we can deploy a **RRAS** on Azure VM, configure this VPN authenticate with user and password, so we should use password to connect RRAS VPN, then use password to login the Azure VM.